# Ubuntu Cross-Compiling QT for Raspberry Pi | ERROR: Unknown command line option 'skip'

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I am fairly very new to Ubuntu/Linux and am currently running into an issue with getting an ERROR: Unknown command not found. I am trying configure Qt for cross compilation for a raspberry pi. I have looked up for similar issues but to no avail unfortunately.

The code I am running is as follows

```
./configure -release -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi3-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=~/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot ~/raspi/sysroot -opensource -confirm-license -make libs -prefix /usr/local/qt5pi -extprefix ~/raspi/qt5pi -hostprefix ~/raspi/qt5 -v -qpa eglfs -no-xcb -system-freetype -skip qtwebengine -nomake examples -nomake tools -fontconfig
```

I need to skip a few things in it but when I run this I get this line

> ERROR: Unknown command line option '-skip'.

For some extra info, this is my location when doing so as follows when typing in pwd

> /home/usr/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3/qtbase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Configure` is not recognizing the `skip` option, because you are running it from `qtbase` folder. Try to tun configure from the top qt folder.

Comment: So should I try to run it from qt-everywhere or from raspi if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: /home/usr/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.3